# JQuery dialog closes after 2 clicks instead of the first click

Tags: jquery-ui

At first I was getting this error: `cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization`. But several suggestions to the solution was tho add the `context: this,` to the ajax call.

The entire problem began after I started using a Partial view instead of the view

Here is my code:

```
$("#ContactDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    hide: "fade",
    show: "bounce",
    height: $(window).height() / 2,
    width: $(window).width() / 2,
    title: "Send email",
    open: function () {

    },
    buttons: [{ 
        text: "Send", click: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,                    
                type: "POST",
                data: {},
                context: this,
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "html", //xml, json, script and html
                success: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");                     
                },
```

The dialog will close, but only after 2 click on the button. I have also tried doing:

```
$("#contactDialog").dialog("close");
```

Has it something to do with the loading of the js file?
The script is referenced in the `_Layout.cshtml` like so:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/OwnedScripts/ContDia.js"></script>
```

I also tried moving it to the Partial view, but no luck
Anyone has an idea what might be the problem?
And I want to solve this without hacks if possible please :-)

Comment: So I have found out that when the Partial view is loaded, it opens to dialogs, and since they have the same exact position, it looks as if there is only one dialog that needs 2 clicks before it closes. But they actually close by 1 click. But I can't find out why it opens 2 dialog windows when I'm using Partial view? If I switch back to using View, then it works fine. There is no where in the code where I call the dialog window twice, it is simply because I'm using partial view